# Extract vertices data (x,y,z) from fbx file (C#)

Tags: c#, autodesk, fbx

How can I extract vertices data (X,Y,Z) from a *.fbx 3D model?

Is there any free (and reliable) library for that in C# ?

**Note:** FBX (sometimes called "Filmbox") is a 3D file format (by Autodesk) to move 3D data between software packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's reliable but it has MIT license. https://github.com/DomCR/MeshIO